# generate matrix within iterations in R

Tags: r, matrix

I had posted this earlier but it got too long. I am unsure how to append the requisite data iteratively to a matrix. Any help is much appreciated. My example is given below -

```
set.seed(20430)
n   = 1000
k   = 3

fileA = rnorm(n)
fileB = rnorm(n)
fileC = rnorm(n)
positions = paste("randomPos_",rnorm(n),sep="")
betas <- cbind(fileA, fileB, fileC)
for(j in 1:k){
   for(i in 1:n){
        x[i,j] = (positions[i]*betas[j])
   }
}
```

Results:

```
Error in positions[i] * betas[j] : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Comment: The `positions` vector has text (character) values. They cannot be multiplied by anything.

Comment: In real world, its actually a genomic position given as chromosome_start position eg.  chr1_23456. The idea is to create a matrix of beta values for each individual position.

Comment: Whatever the idea is, the expression `positions[i]*betas[j]` cannot be executed as you are multiplying a text by a number.